# Transform 89h 16'57" to minutes in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a cell with the value:

`89h 16'57"`

Is there some way I can transform this to minutes in Excel, so the new value will be:

`5356,57`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using the "Text-to-column" function in Excel and after that removing the last charaters (for example "h") by using: `=LEFT(G1; LEN(G1)-1)`.